# Kaminari error when collection is smaller than per(x)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, pagination, kaminari

I am running the Kaminari gem for my pagination.

Controller

```
def dashboard
  @projects = Project.find_by_user_id(current_user)
  if @projects.size > 10
    @projects.page(params[:page]).per(10)
  end
end
```

Dashboard view

```
= paginate @projects, :theme => 'twitter-bootstrap-3', :remote => true
```

In my case, the @projects is sometimes only 1 record or even zero records. When it is nil, I get an error on the params[:page] being nil.

So this works

```
def dashboard
  @projects = Project.page(params[:page]).per(10)
end
```

This gets error `undefined method 'page' for #<Project:0x007f8cac5f14b0>`

```
  def dashboard
    @projects = Project.find_by_user_id(current_user).page(params[:page]).per(10)
  end
```

I think it is because the @projects is only a couple of records which is less than the 10 specified in .per

I tried adding a @projects.count or @projects.size but I get the error `undefined method 'size' for #<Project:0x007f8c996865f0>`

```
def dashboard
  @projects = Project.find_by_user_id(current_user)
  if @projects.size > 10
    @projects.page(params[:page]).per(10)
  end
end
```

What the hell am I doing wrong!? haha

I am guessing I can fix this in the first instance instead of trying to fix the second or third options. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is `Project.find_by_user_id(current_user)` returns an `Array`, not an `ActiveRecord::Relation`

You should do something like:

```
current_user.projects.page(params[:page]).per(10)
```

If your relationships are correctly setup.

Or:

```
Project.where(user_id: current_user.id).page(params[:page]).per(10)
```

Comment: Awesome! Thanks. So I have assumed all this time that an ActiveRecord query only returns hashes. Is there a resource I can read to see whether I am requesting a hash or an array. My head is killing me from all the reading at night of all the books so I am trying but just didn't 'get that'. Thanks again

Comment: `Project.find_by_user_id(current_user).class`, `current_user.projects.class`